# How does django work with websocket server and webserver simultaneously?

Tags: django, websocket, webserver, django-channels

I think I have some confusion in the understanding of websocket server and webserver.

So I followed the tutorial of django channels, where I created a little app that listens on a channel and returns some response.

At the same time, I can still serve webpages with normal view functions, so how does django do this magic so that it works without me modifying anything in the nginx server config?

Comment: Did you [read the documentation for Channels](http://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/inshort.html) mentions how this works:

> It separates Django into two process types:
>
> One that handles HTTP and WebSockets
>
> One that runs views, websocket handlers and background tasks (consumers)
>      They communicate via a protocol called ASGI, which is similar to WSGI but runs over a network and allows for more protocol types. [...] probably [Daphne](https://github.com/django/daphne/)